# Google Analytics dash or not to dash

Tags: android, google-analytics

This is a follow up question to these question:

[encode the dash or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345307/encode-the-dash-or-not)

[Google Analytics SDK in your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371183/google-analytics-sdk-in-your-app)

I still don't get if I should use the dash in the configuration file or not. The answers to both questions seems conflicting to me as in the analytics guide itself:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#analytics-xml

So should I use dashes in the configuration file in the form of `UA-XXXXXXX-Y` or should it be `UAXXXXXXXY`? If it should be WITH dashs then what does the warning to not encode dashes means? If I should NOT write the dashes then why is the example involves dashes and a specific way to ignore the warning about the dash writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing... The answer is to dash